# How can I use lseek() to get to the midpoint of a file?

Tags: c, file, read-write, seek, lseek

So I have a textfile with 10 words with 5 characters each, and I want to get to the midpoint of that file without having to call read multiple times so I wanted to use lseek. As I understand, lseek only uses the SET, CUR, and END flags.

So If I have a textfile and all the words are only 5 words long...

I can use `SEEK_SET` to get the current word I'm at which would be 5

I can use `SEEK_CUR` to get to the next word location, so 10, then 15 and so on

I can use `SEEK_END` to get to 100.

My question is, if I want to get somewhere in between, say spot 76 or 24, or in my case 50, how can I do that? I tried doing using lseek with SEEK_SET / 2 and it doesn't work.

Comment: I assume you have a single space/delimiter between each (5 char) word, so that's 6 chars/word for all but the last. So, position is `ipos * 6` where `ipos` is the Nth word (origin 0) you want (e.g. 0, 1, 2, ..., 9). So, 10/5 --> 5 --> 5 * 6 --> 30. So, `lseek(fd,30,SEEK_SET);` Or, more generally, `lseek(fd,ipos * 6,SEEK_SET);` Obviously, if you do _not_ have a delimeter between words, the multiplier is 5 instead of 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused as to what these flags do.  From the man page:

> SYNOPSIS
> #include <sys/types.h>
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> ```
>    off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
> The lseek() function repositions the offset of the open file associated
> with the file descriptor fd to the argument  offset  according  to  the
> directive whence as follows:
>
> ```
>    SEEK_SET
>           The offset is set to offset bytes.
>
>    SEEK_CUR
>           The offset is set to its current location plus offset bytes.
>
>    SEEK_END
>           The offset is set to the size of the file plus offset bytes.
> ```

So you would use `SEEK_SET` to go to a specific location in the file, `SEEK_CUR` to go to a location relative to the current location, and `SEEK_END` to go to a location relative to the end of the file.

In your case, if you have 10 words of 5 characters each for a total of 50 bytes and want to go to the middle, you want to use `SEEK_SET` with an offset of 25.  For example:

```
lseek(fd, 25, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of using SEEK_SET with an offset of 25? Or any offset / numer? I  am not familiar with the syntax and whatever tests I  run on it are not getting the results I want.

Comment: @mistahwhite See my edit.

Comment: Thanks I was confusing myself by using a variable. Didn't fully grasp it's usage till your edit. Thanks again